# how to block require file in php when php form is submitted?

Tags: php

Is it possible to block or quit or any other function to stop the require file,
and when I mean require I mean,

```html
<?php
require 'passwordpopup.php';
?>
```

so before the user goes into the form the page asks the user for a password, when the user enters the password successfully and then submit the form of the page that was asking for the password the page sends the data to another page, the other page redirects the user to the page of the form and echo the data, but when the page redirects the user to the main page the page of the password pops ups again, I know what I said is confusing and I'm confused as well lol, so basically I only want to know if I can require the file passwordpopup.php only once not more than 1 time and how can I do that?

Comment: `if (your_condition == true) {require 'passwordpopup.php';}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
if(!isset($_POST)){
    require 'passwordpopup.php';
}
```

Basically what this says `if` the `$_POST` req hasn't been made, then require the form. If you wanted it the other way around you could do `if(isset($_POST)){}`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this using `if` condition in two scenario as belows

**1..** If you are setting up a session using username and password. Put `require` statement in if condition and check if the session is not set only then process the require statement.

**2..** You can also check if `$_POST` is set or not. Again put the if condition and that only process the require statement if `$_POST` is not set.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to block or quit or any other function to stop the
>   require file, and when I mean require I mean,

The possible solution is to set an identifier or set and if condition and if the condition is satisfied you will require the file.

```
//lets say you will execute require if the $_POST global variable has been set
if(isset($_POST)){
  require 'passwordpopup.php';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Check if you submitted form and then do not add this file. It might help you

```
<?php
if(!(isset($_POST) && count($_POST))) {
   require 'passwordpopup.php';
}
?>
```